# Headers in 3rd party frameworks on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, frameworks, header, sparkle

I'm using the Sparkle framework in Qt. I've added the following to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -framework Sparkle
QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS += -F/path/to/the/directory/sparkle.framework/is/in
```

However I get a compilation error saying "Sparkle/Sparkle.h" cannot be found. Framework headers physically reside in MyFramework.framework/Headers/*.h and are included like MyFramework/*.h

What commands do I need to add to my .pro file to properly include the Sparkle framework headers?

Comment: I copied the framework into /System/Library/Frameworks and I was able to get it to compile. I still can't get it to link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, I needed to use `QMAKE_CFLAGS` for the compiler to include the headers.

Comment: I believe it's `QMAKE_LFLAGS` by this source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-platform-notes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`INCLUDEPATH`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) in the `.pro` file.

From docs,

**This variable specifies the #include directories which should be searched when compiling the project. Use ';' or a space as the directory separator.**

So, in your case it will be like,

```
INCLUDEPATH = MyFramework.framework/Headers
```

where

`MyFramework.framework/Headers` is the **physical location** of the headers.

I never been used to MAC OS but still hope it helps..

**Edit**:

If you want to include like `FrameWorkName/HeaderFile.h` you can stop with specifying upto the desired folder.

For e.g,

If `home/CommonFolder/FrameWorkName/HeaderFile.h` is your header file's physical location,  you can give the `INCLUDEPATH` as

```
INCLUDEPATH = home/CommonFolder
```

Now In your **.cpp** you can give like `#include "FrameWorkName/HeaderFile.h"`,

Comment: No, this does not work because you are meant to include `FrameworkName/someheader.h`, not `someheader.h` directly.

Comment: @ Is there any specific reason you want not to include directly and include like `FrameworkName/someheader.h` ??

Comment: Yes, that's how you're supposed to include all framework headers, and the headers inside that framework have `#include <Framework/otherheader.h>` in them, so it HAS to be done this way. For frameworks residing in /Library/Frameworks it seems to work automagically, but anywhere else it's a problem...